# Dynamically converting all float type columns to decimal

Tags: sql-server, dynamic, decimal, sql-server-2014, precision

I need to convert all float data type columns to decimal with precision in all tables in a particular database.

I have the following code:

```
DECLARE @sql VARCHAR(8000)

SELECT 
    @sql = COALESCE(@sql + ',', '') + 
           CASE DATA_TYPE 
              WHEN 'float' THEN 'CAST(' + COLUMN_NAME  + ' AS DECIMAL(28, 10))'
              ELSE COLUMN_NAME
           END
FROM
    INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
WHERE 
    DATA_TYPE = 'float'

EXEC ('SELECT '+ @sql + ' FROM TABLE_NAME')
```

I also have another version with the decimal scale as a variable:

```
DECLARE 
    @sql NVARCHAR(MAX),
    @DecimalPlace INT = 10

SELECT
    @sql = COALESCE(@sql + ',', '') + 
           CASE DATA_TYPE 
              WHEN 'float' 
                 THEN 'CAST(' + COLUMN_NAME  + ' AS DECIMAL(28, ' + CAST(@DecimalPlace AS NVARCHAR) + '))'
                 ELSE COLUMN_NAME
           END
FROM
    INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
WHERE 
    DATA_TYPE = 'float'

EXEC ('SELECT '+ @sql + ' FROM TABLE_NAME')
```

I am currently getting the following error for my topmost script:

> Msg 156, Level 15, State 1, Line 1
>   Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'from'.

I see my issue... 'from TABLE_NAME' is invalid. Here's the SQL generated...

```
SELECT
    CAST(DWF_ORDERS_EXCHANGE_RATE_DOL AS DECIMAL(28,10)),
    CAST(DWF_ORDERS_ITEM_DISCOUNT_PRC AS DECIMAL(28,10)),
    CAST(DWF_ORDERS_SALES_QTY AS DECIMAL(28,10)),
    CAST(DWF_ORDERS_OPEN_QTY 
FROM
    TABLE_NAME
```

It appears as though my logic can only accommodate one table at a time. Is there a relatively easy way to modify my logic in order to accommodate multiple tables fed into a variable?

Additionally, I'm not sure what would be the best practice in order to keep the original float precision/scale if applicable.

Using SQL Server 2014.

Comment: Hi Dale.  It wasn't obvious.  I've done so using print @sql, and all it gives me was the following: Cast(DWF_ORDERS_EXCHANGE_RATE_DOL as decimal(28,10)),Cast(DWF_ORDERS_ITEM_DISCOUNT_PRC as decimal(28,10)),...

Comment: Dale.  Okay.  I see my issue.  from TABLE_NAME is invalid.  Here's the entire SQL... select Cast(DWF_ORDERS_EXCHANGE_RATE_DOL as decimal(28,10)),Cast(DWF_ORDERS_ITEM_DISCOUNT_PRC as decimal(28,10)),Cast(DWF_ORDERS_SALES_QTY as decimal(28,10)),Cast(DWF_ORDERS_OPEN_QTY as  from TABLE_NAME

Comment: That means that I also need to pass all my tables as a parameter.  I'm not sure how to modify my code to accommodate, multiple tables as it seems that my logic is good for only one table.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following script will iterate through all the tables with a float column and generate the dynamic SQL with the correct table name:

```
declare @Table table ([Name] nvarchar(max), Handled bit default(0));
declare @Sql nvarchar(max), @TableName nvarchar(max);

insert into @Table ([Name])
  select TABLE_NAME
  from INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
  where DATA_TYPE = 'float'
  group by TABLE_NAME;

while exists (select 1 from @Table where Handled = 0) begin
  select top 1 @TableName = [Name] from @Table where Handled = 0;

  select @Sql = coalesce(@sql+',','') + 
    case DATA_TYPE 
    when 'float' then 'cast(' + COLUMN_NAME  + ' as decimal(28,10))'
    else COLUMN_NAME
    end
  from INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
  where DATA_TYPE = 'float' and TABLE_NAME = @TableName;

  set @Sql = 'select '+ @Sql + ' from ' + @TableName;

  print(@Sql);
  --exec (@Sql);

  update @Table set Handled = 1 where @TableName = [Name];
end
```